# play framework bind data from request

Tags: playframework-2.0

I'm attempting to do a binding of request data to a pojo by calling `.bindFromRequest()`. I have defined a simpleformatter for `String[]` and needs to map several params with different names to this array. So, instead of the default mapping where the java field name is used to map the form field name, I need to match it by regexp or something, if possible. So I have :

```
public class ChallengeData {
    @Required
    String[] rivals;
}
```

And the request contains params on the form `?rival1=abc&rival2=def&rival3=ghi` etc. So when doing `Form.form(ChallengeData.class).bindFromRequest()` I would like the values to be put into the rivals array. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you send your data with the regular syntax, or is it a constraint ? `?rivals[]=abc&rivals[]=def&rivals[]=ghi` ?

Comment: i must receive it on the specified form :/